# Stream public tracks from SoundCloud to custom html5 player, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, audio, soundcloud, audio-player

I found a good custom HTML5 audio player and successfully redesigned it for my needs. Now I want to stream a publicly available tracks from SoundCloud to my new player. I had tried to add api.soundcloud.com (all variations) links to "scr" property with no luck. I spent several hour googling for the solution - nothing so far.

If I understand it correctly to stream "public" tracks I don't need a "Client ID", so I don't know what to do to make it work. Is it more than just a add api link to "scr"?

I'd tried this (adding api link to scr, track id is just an example):

```html
<div class="audio-player">
    <div id="play-btn"></div>
    <div class="audio-wrapper" id="player-container" href="javascript:;">
      <audio id="player" ontimeupdate="initProgressBar()">
     <source src="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/2775534">
   </audio>
    </div>
    <div class="player-controls scrubber">
      <p>Oslo <small>by</small> Holy Esque</p>
      <span id="seekObjContainer">
     <progress id="seekObj" value="0" max="1"></progress>
   </span>
      <br>
      <small style="float: left; position: relative; left: 15px;" class="start-time"></small>
      <small style="float: right; position: relative; right: 20px;" class="end-time"></small>

    </div>
    <div class="album-image" style="background-image: url('https://artwork-cdn.7static.com/static/img/sleeveart/00/051/614/0005161476_350.jpg')"></div>
  </div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/luke__duncan/pen/dpZVOr) (original player source code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK SoundCloud has stopped accepting the new app registration but if you already have a client_id, you can use this

You need to provide the "streaming_url" of the track in the audio player source, which will look something like this, I can't provide my "client_id" here as it may break the rule of the community but just a google search can give you lot of working "client_id" for track id you can use this: 459194895

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/{trackid}/stream?client_id={clientid}
```

Comment: Even for “public” tracks? Are you sure? The SC api documentation says that it is not necessary for that kind of tracks, quote “You can skip Client ID part if track is public” @Shubham

Comment: Yes, client id is required, to help you I have added a client id in the codepen link and you can check that, secondly can you give me a public track id to check it further.

Comment: tracks/346727166, if it helps, just is an example @Shubham

Comment: I'm trying to play audio from SoundCloud in the CodPen, and, it is not loading, 403 error, should I pursue this method with a SC id, or it is not working anymore (in 2018) @Shubham

Comment: @AndrewK there is a limit for each client id and for the given client id the limit has been reached and will rest on "2018/08/14 09:10:32 +0000" so you have to wait or you can use another client id

Comment: Thank for heads up!, now I can pursue knows that this method is working